# Triggers with IF statment result in Mysql Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hello All I'm struggling with the following query it create a trigger and it give syntax error can someone help me with  that.

**MySQL version 5.7.14**

Code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_itgwp_users_insert` AFTER
INSERT ON `itgwp_users`
FOR EACH ROW
    IF USER() = 'root@localhost' THEN
        INSERT INTO audits (OPERATION, row_id,TABLE_NAME,`logical_table_name`,`status`)
        VALUES ('insert',
                NEW.ID,
                'itgwp_users',
                'contacts',
                'need_approve');

    END IF;
```

This trigger works but not the above one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_wp_posts_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `itgwp_posts`
 FOR EACH ROW IF  USER() = 'wp_sync@localhost' THEN
    INSERT INTO audits (operation, row_id,table_name,`logical_table_name`) values ('insert', NEW.ID, 'itgwp_posts', NEW.post_type);
    END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to start by changing the delimiter and then use a begin end block

```
DELIMITER %%
CREATE TRIGGER `after_itgwp_users_insert` AFTER
INSERT ON `itgwp_users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF USER() = 'root@localhost' THEN
        INSERT INTO audits (OPERATION, row_id,TABLE_NAME,`logical_table_name`,`status`)
        VALUES ('insert',
                NEW.ID,
                'itgwp_users',
                'contacts',
                'need_approve');

    END IF;
END %%
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working. I will accept your answer after 7min that's rules of stackoverflow ^_^

Comment: No worries. glad to have been of help

Comment: When I have time I will check those new keywords for me.

Comment: it's just that whenever multiple statements are using in mysql, you have to identify the start of a block with `BEGIN` and where it ends you have to put `END`.

Comment: Sincel using multiple statements means you have to use `;` to mark the end of each statements, you have to tell mysql that you are temporarily changing the default delimiter to something else so that the query can be typed in (or send through a program)